# Create button to reset the counter

Tags: flutter, button

I'm trying to learn flutter and my first 'APP' is a counter. The counter was working, but I would like to increment it and put a button to reset the count. Here's my code:

'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple), home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var count = 0;

  void reset() {
    count = 0;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void increment() {
    count++;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Meu Primeiro APP!"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Contador\n$count",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          increment();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
'''
```

I've done searches on the internet and still haven't found the solution to this problem, which apparently is simple to solve.

Comment: Hey, if I helped you out I´d appreciate if you could accept my answer. If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create a new button with that functionality of resetting your counter variable. Wrap your center widget with a column and add a new button like this:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Contador\n$count",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Reset Counter"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count = 0;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

In order to see the counter updating on your screen you have to call the increment method inside of setState() so the framework schedules a rebuild!

```
  void increment() {        
    setState(() {
     count++;
    });
  }
```

I suggest you do some tutorials on the [official flutter site](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) to get started with the core fundamentals of flutter - happy coding! :)